# why cannot create rarecurve in vegan?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to create rarefaction curves for my data but my raremax and Srare are  equal to zero and rarecurve does not create any curve. I have 36 obs and 52 variables, I am trying to assess any potential underestimation of species richness due to low sample size. I think that since the raremax is zero it will not create any curve. Thanks

This is my code:

```
library(vegan)
      Moo<-read.csv("data.csv", strip.white=T)

  #total number of species at each site (row of data)
  S <- specnumber(Moo)
  S
[1]  6  9  3  6 12  3 10  5  3  6  6  8  4 12  3  2  5  0  3  4  4  5  3 10  7  1  3 11 11
[30]  4  4  3  5  4  2  5
# Number of INDIVIDUALS per site 
 raremax <- min(rowSums(Moo)) 

raremax
[1] 0 
Srare <- rarefy(Moo, raremax)
Srare
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0
attr(,"Subsample")
[1] 0

#Plot rarefaction results
 par(mfrow = c(1,2))
 plot(S, Srare, xlab = "Observed No. of Species", 
 ylab = "Rarefied No. of Species",
 main = " plot(rarefy(Moo, raremax))")
  abline(0, 1)
  rarecurve(Moo, step = 20, 
      sample = raremax, 
      col = "blue", 
      cex = 0.6,
      main = "rarecurve()")

'> head(Moo)
   Trapezia.aereolata Trapezia.globosa Trapezia.formosa Trapezia.lutea Trapezia.punctimanus
1                  0                0                0              5                    0
2                  0                0                0              5                    0
3                  0                0                0              4                    0
4                  0                0                0              8                    0
5                  0                0                0              6                    0
6                  0                0                0              2                    0
    Trapezia.septata Trapezia.serenei Trapezia.tigrina Alpheus.lottini Alpheus.sp..White
1                0                0                0               4                 0
2                0                0                0               4                 0
3                0                0                0               0                 0
4                0                0                0               2                 0
5                0                0                0               4                 0
6                0                0                0               1                 0
    Acanthanas.sp. Ophiuroids Ophiocoma.erinaceous Ophiocoma.sp Ophiactis.sp.
1              0          3                    0            0             0
2              0          1                    0            0             0
3              0          0                    0            0             0
4              0          1                    0            0             0
5              0          0                    0            0             0
6              0          0                    0            0             0
    Echinometra.sp. Chlamys.sp. Conus.sp. Psaumis.cavipes Tiarina.sp. Calcinus.sp.
1               0           0         0               1           1            0
2               0           0         0               0           0            2
3               0           0         0               0           0            0
4               0           0         0               0           0            0
5               0           0         0               0           0            0
6               0           0         0               0           0            0
    Harpiliopsis.sp. Jocaste.sp. Pilodius.pugil Pilodius.sp. Coralliocaris Chrysopetalum.Sp.
1                0           0              0            0             0                 0
2                0           0              0            1             2                 2
3                0           0              0            1             0                 0
4                0           0              0            0             2                 0
5                0           0              0            0             2                 1
6                0           0              0            0             0                 0
    Menathius.sp. Chlorodiella.nigra Chlorodiella.sp. Synalpheus.sp. Labrid..wrasse.
1             0                  0                0              0               0
2             1                  1                0              0               0
3             0                  0                0              2               0
4             0                  0                0              0               1
5             0                  0                0              0               0
6             0                  0                0              0               0
    Liomera.cinctimana Domecia.hispida Domecia Eviota.Sp. Paguris.sp. Palaemonidae Majiidae
1                  0               0       0          0           0            0        0
2                  0               0       0          0           0            0        0
3                  0               0       0          0           0            0        0
4                  1               0       0          0           0            0        0
5                  0               0       1          1           1            1        0
6                  0               0       0          0           0            0        0
   Cerithium.litteratum Cerithium.sp. Granulina..margaritula. Coralliophila.monodonta
1                    0             0                       0                       0
2                    0             0                       0                       0
3                    0             0                       0                       0
4                    0             0                       0                       0
5                    1             3                       0                       0
6                    0             0                       0                       0
  Muricidae Tanaeid Unknown.shell. Amphipoda Polychaeta Strombus..marginatus.. Buccinidae
1         0       0              0         1          0                      0          0
2         0       0              0         0          0                      0          0
3         0       0              0         0          0                      0          0
4         0       0              0         0          0                      0          0
5         0       1              1         0          0                      0          0
6         0       0              0         1          0                      0          0
 gastropod..glasslike.shell Drupella
1                          0        0
2                          0        0
3                          0        0
4                          0        0
5                          0        0
6                          0        0'
```

Comment: You take the minimum of the vector of `rowSums(moo)` (or `specnumber(Moo)` ), and `S[18]` is equal to 0, so the minimum of `S` is 0.

Comment: Ok I understand that but then also my Srare equals zero and when I plot rarecurve I don't have any curve.

Comment: Because once `raremax == 0`, when you do `rarefy(Moo, raremax)`, you take a subsample of size 0 from Moo.

Comment: How can I fix this? Thanks for explaining

Comment: With rarefaction, you're trying to see whether the size of your sample affects your estimate of species richness. A 0-sample will give you 0 species richness. So to circumvent, you can simply pass an arbitrary non-zero, small value (e.g. 1) or vector of values, to the `sample` argument in `rarefy()`.